# How pull in other pages' templates and content and output those on a "combining" page?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

Imagine I have the following setup:

```
* Combining Page (Template: Combine Template)
    * Sub Page 1 (Template: Basic Template)
    * Sub Page 2 (Template: Other Template)
    * Sub Page 3 (Template: Basic Template)
```

So I have three sub pages, two of which have the same template (which uses custom fields as well as regular content). I want the parent page's template to be able to work like this:

**PSEUDO-CODE:**

```
//Show the content for this combine page (e.g. a title)
if ( have_posts() ) : while ...this is the main loop...

$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_pages = $wp_query->query( array( "post_type" => "page", "posts_per_page" => -1 ) );

//Get child pages
$child_pages = get_page_children( $post->ID, $all_pages );

//Loop through child pages so we can add their HTML (made from applying their content to their templates)
foreach( $child_pages as $child_page )
{
    /** WHAT DO I DO HERE? **/
    //Pseudo code
    $child_page_template = get_page_template( $child_page->page_name );
    $child_output = apply_to( $child_page_template, get_page_content( $child_page->content ) );
}
```

**EDIT**
In addition, on the child page, I get a custom field and loop through it:

```
$values = get_post_custom_values( "mycustomfield" );
foreach ( $values as $value ) echo $value . "<br>";
```

**END EDIT**

How would I do this?

Is there anything built in to do this? Or would I need to use output buffers to isolate everything and print each to a buffer from within a function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your perspective is just incorrect for the goal you're trying to reach.

Your pseudo code is reminiscent of a funky iframe style approach. Simply breaking your children pages into what WordPress calls "Template Parts" (basically PHP includes) would be the way to solve this (assuming I understand you correctly). Since Template Parts can be recycled and also have some WordPress-specific benefits when it comes to looping and passing arguments and stuff.

Comment: how would I tie pages to template specific parts? I want the cms admin (who won't understand code) to be able to choose from different layouts for pages and to keep that layout on its part of the combined page.

Comment: That's kind of two different questions: 1. Documentation regarding how to create Template Parts and utilize them best is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part. 2. How to allow an admin to choose them is a totally separate question I'd recommend creating a new thread for. But the Codex has an explanation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates